# Can I pipe live data from the \watch command of postgresql into another command?

Tags: pipe, tail, postgresql

I'd like to pipe live data from psql into another command for purposes of monitoring via the shell.

Can this be done?

So far I have the following:

```
$ psql bareos -c '\watch (SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 200) TO STDOUT WITH CSV'
```

I'm using postgres 11.12.

But when I run the command, I end up with the error:

```
\watch cannot be used with an empty query
```

Whereas, if I run it directly from psql, it's perfectly capable of watching the live output.

My goal is to achieve unix style tailing of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried several variations with `-c` and couldn't get it to work.  It looks like either I didn't try enough variations, or `\watch` just doesn't work with `psql -c`.

I then tried it with `psql -f` (to read the sql script from a file) and [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to provide the sql script "file", and it worked just fine.

For example:

```
psql --csv -f <(printf '%s\n' \
                 'SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 200;' \
                 '\watch')
```

or, if your `psql` doesn't support the `--csv` option:

```
psql -f <(printf '%s\n' \
           '\pset format csv' \
           'SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 200;' \
           '\watch')
```

The `printf` command sends **two** sql commands to `psql` (the `select`, and then the `\watch`), separated by a newline character (`\n`).   Each of these commands has to be single-quoted separately, so that they are separate arguments to `printf`.

Note that SQL also uses single-quotes in many commands, so if you need to run an SQL command which uses them, you'll have to be very careful with how you quote your commands.  e.g.

```
psql -f <(printf '%s\n' "select * from table where name='cas'" '\watch 5')
```

In this example, I'm using double-quotes in the first SQL command to avoid any problems with the quoted string `'cas'`.   The catch is that double-quotes in shell allow variable interpolation, so you need to escape any shell variables names (e.g. `\$var` instead of just `$var`) if you want the literal string rather than the value of the variable. e.g.

```
psql -f <(printf '%s\n' \
            "select * from table where pass='\$1\$QsHP.S0S\$1Npjv4aKJZv4IjDD.PgNp/'" \
            '\watch 5')
```

Note that I had to escape every occurence of `$` with a `\` to prevent the shell from expanding parts of the string that look like they're variable names.

Comment: It doesn't like my `TO` for some reason.

Comment: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"`

Comment: use `psql`'s `--csv` option.  I've edited my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: *sigh* it doesn't appear to have that option.

Comment: according to `man psql` (I'm running pg version 14), `--csv` the option is equivalent to `\pset format csv`, so try adding that (in single-quotes) as the first printf string, before the select command